# Where to initialize a derived field?

Tags: java

I have a class `X` with `x1`, `x2`, etc. as its fields. I need to define a key for class `X` (which uniquely identifies an instance of class `X`). So I created a class Key with the fields subset of class `X`. An instance of class Key will be a field of Class `X`. What is the best place to initialize the key?

```
public class X {
   int x1;
   int x2;
   int x3;
   Key key;
}

public class Key {
   int x1;
   int x3;
}
```

I have override equals and hashcode methods which should work based on key.

Comment: What should the values of `key.x1` and `key.x3` be? Will they be generated at runtime? Will they be static? It depends on what you're initializing the fields with.

Comment: Once initialized the values of fields of X will not change

Comment: But what will the values be? Will they be random? Or are they known at compile-time?

Comment: Not known at compile time

Answer (score 1):

I would not keep the Key class as a field. I would consider providing a getter which would return a new key instance each time it is called.

Better yet, the key class could hold reference to X and access its fields whenever equals/hash are called. That way you will never have to manually update any value of key whatsoever.

Then again, you could just implement `hashCode` and `equals` in X and use a `HashSet` instead of a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

If the key is supposed to be unique to each *instance* of X, then just generate it in the constructor method.